# Increase page size?

Tags: sqlite

I was reading on efficient handling of blobs in SQLite (see [Faster alternative to sqlite3_blob_open](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Faster-alternative-to-sqlite3-blob-open-td62030.html)).

One of the suggestions is:

> Bump up the page size of your database. The default of 1kb isn't that
>   good a fit

Searching for the obvious terms is not producing useful results.

How does one increase the page size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `PRAGMA`:

```
PRAGMA page_size = <size>;
```

(Specify  in bytes.)

http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_page_size

Comment: Please look at the other answer which tells that due to the increase in the default value of page size in newer versions of SQLite this answer actually reduces the page size.

Comment: `PRAGMA page_size = 4096; VACUUM;` default page_size is 4096. page_size must be one of: 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536

Answer (score 6):

In case you come across this answer without further reading, bear in mind that the default page size has changed. In SQLite version 3.12.0 (2016-03-29)) it was increased to 4096 bytes. So, the answer above was correct in 2014 when it was posted, but the value of 2048 now makes the page size smaller.

Please see https://sqlite.org/pgszchng2016.html